# /alfresco/api/service/people only returns 5000 results in Alfresco EE 4.1.4

Tags: alfresco

I've run into a problem where a call to `https://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people` is only returning the first 5000 users.

I can't figure out how to get the rest out of the system--that API doesn't appear to support a "skipCount" argument.

I thought that I might be able to get at least a list of the usernames by using the WebDAV URL (`https://localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav/User%20Homes/`) to get the list, but that also only returns the first 5000.

So, how do I get the list of users from 5001 onwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a maxResult param you can give.

for e.g. `https://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/people?filter=*&maxResults=10000`

If you look at this JIRA ticket, you'll see that when you supply a * in the query it will search through SOLR and when you don't it'll search the DB.

If you look at the JAVA code beneath:

```
public PagingResults<PersonInfo> getPeople(String pattern, List<QName> filterStringProps, List<Pair<QName, Boolean>> sortProps, PagingRequest pagingRequest)
    {
        ParameterCheck.mandatory("pagingRequest", pagingRequest);
```

There is a **PagingRequest** which you can supply, so you could page that you need the rows/results after 5000.

Still you'd need to make a Java-Backend Webscript which retrieves the result.

**---UPDATE---**

In the org.alfresco.repo.jscript.People there is a maxResult:

```
private int defaultListMaxResults = 5000;
```

If you look a bit further then this class is initiated in the **script-service-context.xml**. 
So just override the bean **peopleScript** and set the defaultListMaxResults to a higher nr, restart Alfresco and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Tahir.  Unfortunately, setting maxResults to 10,000 still only returns 5,000 results.  It looks like it must be hardcoded someplace.

What I don't get is that things like the group membership API (/alfresco/service/api/groups/{groupShortName}/children?authorityType=USER) can take both a "maxitems" and a "skipCount" parameter, making it very easy to write a little loop that pages through.  Since /alfresco/api/service/people only has "maxitems" but not "skipCount", it's impossible to access user 5001 onwards.

Methinks this is a bug...

Comment: Thanks Tahir!  That worked.  I'd still argue that the bug should be fixed by implementing a the skipCount capability on this. 6011 results take quite a while to come back, and I'd imagine this will get even worse--possibly to the point of hitting a timeout before too much longer--as the number of accounts on the system continues to grow. I've had Alfresco support file a bug to that effect.  It's not public yet, but, for reference, it's #MNT-9444.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Have you tried adding filter=*, this way it should access the index files and not the DB.

Comment: Adding filter=*, without your other fix in place, doesn't make a difference.  Still only 5000 results, even when used in conjunction with maxResults=10000.  Maybe that's because we're still using Lucene, not Solr?

Comment: Aah oke, so that could also be probably it. And ofcourse you're free to write you're own Java-Backend implementation using the current one.